# How to write function in Golang to reverse unicode string with only 1 alloc/op?

Tags: go, memory, unicode, reverse, allocation

I need to write my own `reverse.Reverse` analog for unicode strings. This is my code:

```
func Reverse(input string) string {
    runes := []rune(input)

    var result strings.Builder
    result.Grow(len(runes))

    for i := len(runes) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        result.WriteRune(runes[i])
    }

    return result.String()
}
```

But it makes 2 allocs/op:

```
cpu: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-11850H @ 2.50GHz
BenchmarkReverse
BenchmarkReverse-16       297900              7014 ns/op            1792 B/op          2 allocs/op
```

How to make just 1 alloc/op? I know, it's possible

And also i don't understand why `result.Grow(len(runes))` makes 5 allocs/op and `result.Grow(len(input))` - 1 allocs/op

Comment: How do you determine that it makes two allocations? How do you know it's possible to implement this with only one?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share a sample function call as well as what do you get/expect…

Comment: You should start with code that actually reverses Unicode: yours is fundamentally broken.

Comment: Also `Builder.Grow()` requires number of bytes, not runes, so depending on the input your algorithm may use 3 allocs instead of just 2 (if the input contains multi-byte runes) (in extreme scenarios even more).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a strings.Builder with the required capacity.  Write runes from the source string to the builder in reverse order.

```
func Reverse(str string) string {
    var result strings.Builder
    result.Grow(len(str))
    for len(str) > 0 {
        r, size := utf8.DecodeLastRuneInString(str)
        result.WriteRune(r)
        str = str[:len(str)-size]
    }
    return result.String()
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/PNGmFcSTo8q

---

This answer replicates the functionality in the question. I do not claim that the result is meaningful when displayed as glyphs to a human. For example, combining characters do not combine as in the original string.

Here's a contrived example of where the reverse function is useful: An application's string keys for some set of values tend to have common prefixes and uncommon suffixes. The application can improve distribution over the space of strings by reversing the key.

Comment: @smisshin This is not the reverse of the input, https://go.dev/play/p/s1uAmoMNIyQ (for some definitions of “reverse”)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).